# VirtualBox Localhost connection

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, swarm

i have problem with connect to my ubuntu localhost on virtualbox. Host os is windows. On ubuntu i had installed Perforce Swarm Dashboard - in firefox i open it using "localhost" address. I can't reach it from host os. 
Of course i run 2 NIC's on virtualbox:
1 - NAT,
2 - Host-only 
When i try to connect via host web browser with external ip address on ubuntu it show Apache2 ubuntu default page. The most strange is that when i try to open 127.0.0.1 (localhost ip) on webrowser on ubuntu - it show me Apache2 page again... How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand the problem. You cant connect from windows to virtualbox machine(cant access apace webpage)?
Did you try to ping the ip of the virtual machine?
Also try editing virtual machine network adapter settings to bridge mode. If you are able to ping the virtual device then you need to edit apache.conf file and replace deny all to allow all or require local.